# How do you update a Pandas DataFrame with new Indices and Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have

```
     a,   b,   c
u, 111, 112, 113
v, 121, 122, 123
x, 131, 132, 133
```

and

```
     b,   c,   d
x, 211, 212, 213
y, 221, 222, 223
z, 231, 232, 233
```

I want to arrive at:

```
     a,   b,   c,   d
u, 111, 112, 113, NaN
v, 121, 122, 123, NaN
x, 131, 343, 345, 213
y, NaN, 221, 222, 223
z, NaN, 231, 232, 233
```

Here the common data is added. If they are not common the data is retained. If the data is not present on either DF `NaN` is added.

This is like an "outer" add of 2 DataFrames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`df.add`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) over axis 1 with `fill_value` param.

```
# df
#      a    b    c
# u  111  112  113
# v  121  122  123
# x  131  132  133

#df1
#      b    c    d
# x  211  212  213
# y  221  222  223
# z  231  232  233

df.add(df1, axis=1, fill_value=0)

       a      b      c      d
u  111.0  112.0  113.0    NaN
v  121.0  122.0  123.0    NaN
x  131.0  343.0  345.0  213.0
y    NaN  221.0  222.0  223.0
z    NaN  231.0  232.0  233.0
```